# Querying with linq for a non-existent record says System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Querying my sql table with linq for a record that I know doesn't exist I get the following error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object , but .FirstOrDefault() is not supposed to handle it if it doesn't find nothing in database, put the default values?

What I want to do is that if a record does not exist in my database, give a message to the user indicated this, but if the record exists, I want it to bring information

*I created an example so as not to attach all my code and express my failure*

**Code of my main form**

```
namespace Fallas
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numerofactura_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bill = Bill.billfromid (billnumber.Text);
            numerofactura.Text = bill.Numero;
            nombrecliente.Text = bill.Cliente;

        }
```

**Code of my class**

```
namespace Fallas
{

   public class BillModel
    {
        public string Number { get; set; } 
        public string Customer { get; set; }    
        public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }  
    }
    public static class Bill
    {
        public static BillModel billfromid(string number) 
    {
        using AppDatabase db = new AppDatabase();
        {
            Bill fct= (from u in db.vta_factura
                                where u.Numero == number
                       select u).FirstOrDefault();
            if (fct.Factura_ID == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bill not found!", "Atencion!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return new Bill();
            }
            return fct;
        }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from this line:

```
Bill fct= (from u in db.vta_factura
           where u.Numero == number
           select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

When the line ends, if no matching record exists the `fct` variable will be set to `null` (the default value for any class, as per the "or default" part of "`.FirstOrDefault()`"). Then on the next line we have this:

```
if (fct.Factura_ID == 0)
```

You can't look up the `Factura_ID` property (or any other property) on a `null` variable, and so we get the NullReferenceException.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
if (fct is object)
```

Or this:

```
if (fct != null)
```

*`is object` is a relatively recent pattern for checking null in modern C#. It's supposed to be efficient, helps simplify code for some edge cases around nullable/value types, and expresses it in a positive way (no negation).*

Alternatively, you could just return the result from this method, with no check, and let higher-level calling code decide on the best way to respond. Then the method could also be useful in a context where a MessageBox is not appropriate.

Comment: I would go with `fcst is not null` over `fct is object` =)

Comment: @GuruStron Maybe. There is value in removing negations (not/!) from conditional statements.

Comment: @GuruStron For context, the author of this tweet works on the C# language team at MS; https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1115019017297596416

Comment: They both will decompile to the same thing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for the Explanation, this solves my error and helps me understand...
The exception Comes from when I try to query the object later `if (fct.Factura_ID == 0)` I need to fix the error in other places.

Comment: Also statement for not-compiling for structs seems to be plainly wrong according to [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUA9gEYBWApgMbCZgCUhxpQTAQBOWmG4BnTADt6XGQFcIEHgG4Bgkpq3CxEsNKZtO6nUNG0EUzMY7AzKQQF9UzoA) with latest C# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`.FirstOrDefault();` will return null if no records are found